# Grep for a string and then echo a string back from a record

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, grep

I have the following record:

```
MiraServ.log.10:2016/02/07 15:25:13 3 All stations busy!!
MiraServ.log.10:2016/02/07 15:25:13 1 TranHasError (3627,-2) EDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,MI1,IN0019093203,A113214,TK00:027031636:0617:_:V:166056:_:LCLCOCMSN1:LCLCOCMSN1:1448175096,MTR,VOMiraServJava_2_0_13,TH3627,CY124,TC11,SIZ01572S?,O9i5LLI1Yd2XgI90oZ,OA01,HDxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ABD,RC776,AR776,OMNOT COMPLETED,ODSTATION BUSY,DMNOT COMPLETED,RENOT COMPLETED,RMNOT COMPLETED,RYL
MiraServ.log.10:2016/02/07 15:25:13 1 Request  -> EDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,MI1,IN0019093203,A113214,TK00:027031636:0617:_:V:166056:_:LCLCOCMSN1:LCLCOCMSN1:1448175096,MTR,VOMiraServJava_2_0_13,TH3627,CY124,TC11,SIZ01572S?,O9i5LLI1Yd2XgI90oZ,OA01,HDxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ABD,RC776,AR776,OMNOT COMPLETED,ODSTATION BUSY,DMNOT COMPLETED,RENOT COMPLETED,RMNOT COMPLETED,RYL,ATV,CDVisa,OL01
MiraServ.log.10:2016/02/07 15:25:13 1 TxSendPOSResp 0 5 (661) -> EDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,MI1,IN0019093203,A113214,TK00:027031636:0617:_:V:166056:_:LCLCOCMSN1:LCLCOCMSN1:1448175096,MTR,VOMiraServJava_2_0_13,TH3627,CY124,TC11,SIZ01572S?,IDi5LLI1Yd2XgI90oZ,OA01,HDxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ABD,RC776,AR776,OMNOT COMPLETED,ODSTATION BUSY,DMNOT COMPLETED,RENOT COMPLETED,RMNOT COMPLETED,RYL,ATV,CDVisa,OL01,SRN,VEN,CL01,RL01,RO776,RUN,RI  ,CX** TRANSACTION RECORD **\n\nTran. #: 3627\n\nVisa Credit Auth Only\nxxxxxxxxxxxx6056 S\n\n       Amount CAD$132.14\n\n########################\n     NOT COMPLETED      \n########################\n      (776) \nZ01572S?/\nInvoice #: 0019093203\n2016/02/07 15:25:13\n\n     Customer Copy\n,DECredit Auth Only
```

I need to grep for "ODSTATION BUSY" and if it is found (as it would be in the record above), I need to echo back the integer after "Invoice #:" which would be `0019093203` in this case.

There are literally thousands of these records one after another in a `.log` file and I need to get the Invoice number for all records that have the string mentioned above. Im looking to do this in Bash.

Answer (score 1):

`perl -e 'while(<>) {if ($_ =~ qr/ODSTATION BUSY/) { 
     print "$1\n" if $_ =~ /Invoice #:\s+(\d+)/ }
}' <yourfile_goes_here>`

Oh, Bash?

`grep 'ODSTATION BUSY' filename |egrep -o 'Invoice[^0-9]+[0-9]+'|egrep -o '[[:digit:]]+'`

Or:

`awk 'BEGIN{$0 ~ /ODSTATION BUSY/}; gsub(/^.*Invoice #: /,""){print $1}' filename |sed 's/\\n.*$//g'`

Answer (score 1):

POSIX-compliant sed solution which produces 0019093203 from the sample data (assumes Invoice information follows "ODSTATION BUSY"):

```
sed '/.*ODSTATION BUSY.*Invoice #: */!d; s///; s/\\n.*//' file
```

A tweaked version of don_crissti's approach to handle either case:

```
sed -n '/ODSTATION BUSY/s/.*Invoice #: \([0-9]\{1,\}\)\\n.*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: don_crissti: I added a more flexible alternative, based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be:

```
$ grep "ODSTATION BUSY" <filename> | sed 's/^.*Invoice #://;s/\n.*$/'
```

That's pretty ugly, I'm sure there are other, possibly better, ways of pulling this information out using something like `awk`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on GNU sed version 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

if there are too many lines, like in the order of thousands, I prefer to use a temporary file rather than extracting them in the memory and causing system load, but this is a preference of mine.

```
grep "ODSTATION BUSY" logfile > workfile
cat workfile | while read line
do
  invoffset=$(echo ${line} | grep -b -o "Invoice #:"|cut -d: -f1)   #locates string position from the beginning of the string
  invoiceno=$(echo ${line} | cut -c ${invoffset}- | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d"\\" -f1)  # cuts the beginning part of the string, then cuts what is before :, then cuts what is after \
  echo ${invoiceno}
done
```